# Proof of this well-known formula

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm studying this paper of Lieb and Simon, and found what they describe as a well known formula:

$$\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{S_2}\left|r\Omega-y\right|^{-1}d\Omega=\left[\max\left(r,\,\left|y\right|\right)\right]^{-1}$$

Comment: I've amended your answer to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which we prefer to linked images.

Comment: Perhaps you need more explanation of the notations.  (What are $\Omega,r,y,S_2$.   I know $\pi$.) And you need to show what you tried.

Comment: @GEdgar No doubt $S_2$ is the unit $2$-sphere, $\Omega$ is the spherical polar coordinates viz. $d\Omega=\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$, and $r,\,y\in\Bbb R$ with $r>0$. But that leaves open what $r\Omega$ means, and hopefully the OP can clarify this issue. Edit: on second thoughts, if $\Omega$ is the obvious unit vector $y$ may be a vector as well.

Comment: Thank you for amending the image, I struggled to do it myself using iPhone.

Comment: About the details you asked for, Ω is a subset of R3, r>0 is radius of open ball in Ω. S2 is the sphere of radius r.

Comment: @SamKC71 Wait, $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb R^3$? That would mean $r\Omega-y=\{rx-y|x\in\Omega\}$, but what is $\left|r\Omega-y\right|$?